# Update table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to update table but its not working

Here is the code:

```
public Boolean setSectionTickSign(decimal Trans_ID, decimal Job_ID, string SectioName)
{
    string sectionames = "";
    Transcription_Master Trans_Mastr = new Transcription_Master();
    try
    {
        var Trans_Master = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Master where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == Job_ID select new 
        {
            Trans_Mast.Completed_Trans_Sections
        }).Distinct().ToList();
        var complt_trans = Trans_Master.AsEnumerable().Where(dr = > dr.Completed_Trans_Sections != null).ToList();
        if (complt_trans.Count == 0) 
        {
            if (sectionames == "") 
            {
                Trans_Mastr.Completed_Trans_Sections = SectioName;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            Trans_Mastr.Completed_Trans_Sections = "," + SectioName;
        }
        int sc = r2ge.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It does not update database..what is wrong in it??

Comment: Why all the short names?  We don't have any limitations in c# to have short names nor do they pose any problem during compile.  Personally, it's really hard to read, because I have NO idea what `complt_trans` actually means.  I's it *completed* or *complete* or even a *compilation*?  Having to dive into additional code to understand a variable means the code is not easily maintainable.

Comment: You are not modify the `r2ge.Transcription_Master`, but a new copied `Trans_Mastr`

Comment: then how to make change in table @Eric

Comment: It is realy hard to read. Have a look at http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards for naming conventions. Have you set AutoDetectChanges = false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem `Transcription_Master Trans_Mastr = new Transcription_Master();` no need to create new object

```
public Boolean setSectionTickSign(decimal Trans_ID, decimal Job_ID, string SectioName)
{
    string sectionames = "";
    try
    {
        var empQuery = r2ge.Transcription_Master.Where(l => l.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && l.Entity_Id == Job_ID).ToList();

        foreach (Transcription_Master Trans_Mastrr in empQuery)
        {
            if (empQuery.Count == 0)
            {
                if (sectionames == "")
                {
                    Trans_Mastrr.Completed_Trans_Sections = SectioName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Trans_Mastrr.Completed_Trans_Sections = Trans_Mastrr.Completed_Trans_Sections + "," + SectioName;
            }
        }
        int sc = r2ge.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this piece of code to such a thing:

```
 var Trans_Master = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Master 
                     where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID 
                     && Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == Job_ID 
                     select Trans_Mast).Distinct().ToList();
```

In this case Your variable Trans_Maser will be refference to object from collection, so changes will be done on object taken from EF context, and SaveChanges will give correct result.

Comment: You also have two variables with same names:
Transcription_Master Trans_Mastr = new Transcription_Master();

Why are You create here new Transcription_Master()? instead of getting it from EF collection?